# Correlation under transformation

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, random-variable

Suppose i have a random vector $X=(X_1,X_2,...,X_k)^T$ where each $X_i$ has cdf denoted by $F_i$ . The correlation matrix of this multivariate distribution is $R_k$.

Define

$Y_i=\Phi^{-1}(F_i(X_i))$
, where $\Phi$ is standard normal's cdf.

Does the correlation matrix of random vector $Y$ equal $R_k$? Or how this transformation change the correlation matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation is linear association, so every nonlinear transformation $G:=\Phi^{-1}\circ F$ changes it in general. For centered $X_1,X_2$:$$E(X_1X_2)\neq E(G(X_1)G(X_2))$$

More details depend on $G$ or $F$. As one can check, the signs of the correlation do (not) change if $G$ is monotonous (increasing) decreasing.

For further reading I encourage you to search for publications about copulae.

Comment: I agree that the correlation should be different. But if we assume certain correlation structure for $Y$, what can we say about correlation of $X$? Any idea?

Comment: If one has the Copula $C$ betwenn two random variables, the correlation between both is $\frac{12\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (C(F_1(u),F_2(v) - F(u)F(v)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}{Var(X) Var(Y)}$. So not very specific. About the structure of the covariance matrix as a whole, even less is known in this generality.